# A restriction of a vector bundle on a submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

I have an issue with an exercise regarding the construction of the restriction of a given vector bundle.

[image]

Here is what I have:

$\pi: E \to M$ is a vector bundle. Then for every $p \in M$ the fiber $E_p:=\pi^{-1}(\{p\})$ comes with the structure of a k-dimensional real vector space.

Moreover, for every $p \in M$ there is an open set $U \subset M$ with $p \in U$ and a diffeomorphism $\phi: \pi^{-1}(U) \to U \times \mathbb{R}^k$ such that

$$
\pi_k \circ \phi=\pi
$$

where $\pi_k: U \times \mathbb{R}^k \to U, (p,v) \mapsto p$ and for each $p \in U$ the map $\pi_{\mathbb{R}^k} \circ \phi |_{E_p} \to \mathbb{R}^k$ is a vector space isomorphism.

We can define $E |_N:=\cup_{p \in N}$ and consider the restriction $\phi_N: \pi^{-1} |_N (U \cap N) \to (U \cap N) \times \mathbb{R}^k$. This should induce a vector bundle structure.

But now I'm uncertain about how to define $f$. Since $E |_N \subset E$ I thought about taking the inclusion map from $E |_N$ to $E$. But then I'm not sure how to prove $i \circ \pi_N=\pi \circ f$.

Comment: Work in coordinates. Above some point $p \in N$ we (locally) have $(p,v)$ in our vector bundle (over $N$) so that $i \circ \pi_N(p,v) = i (p)=p.$ We want this to equal $\pi \circ f(p,v)$. If we let $(p',v') = f(p,v)$, we want $\pi(p',v')=p'$ to equal $p$, so $p' = p$ so $f(p,v) = (p,v')$. One such choice of $f$ which will obviously extend between the local coordinate patches is the choice $v' = v$, which gives you the restriction bundle